# OSX Icon files in folders

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I've got a real big problem. My OSX (10.9.5) creates `Icon` files in automatic generated folders, mainly in git or gradle build folders.

Does anybody have an idea, how this can be deactivated? With these files, git and gradle have real problems, because the files doesn't belong into the process.

Edit: I found the tool, which created the `Icon` files. It's `Google Drive` and it's really bad.

Comment: Try going into Finder and pressing `Cmd+J` and turning off `Show icon preview` in those folders maybe? Just a guess...

Comment: It seems to work (for now). Hope the IntelliJ build will never generate these `Icon` files anymore. :)

Comment: Yes. Google Drive is bad voodoo. I removed it soon after trying it.